# How do I insert a new frame into existing flv files when playing?

Tags: flash, flv

This is quite often seen on video sites(to insert some advertisements),

the newly inserted frames should be dynamically generated from the web server,

how to implement it myself?

Answer (score 2):

Pause the flv playback programmatically.  Display a static advertisement overlaid over the video or play another flv for the advertisement.  When the advertisement is done, start playing the original flv again.

Comment: I'm not familar with flash,can you be more specific?

Comment: @Runner, there are a few different ways to play video in Flash.  Post some sample code for what you're doing now which we can use as a starting point for suggested changes to integrate ads.

Comment: We're using `flv` to play video.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply separate your video and advertising frames onto different layers in the timeline.
With some planning, your FLV should ideally play on its own without the need to know what is going on around it, then you just layer your additional objects on top.

Comment: The ads should be dynamically generated,and the video should continue after the ads time out.